# axios.delete isnt removing item permanently

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a simple react app that user can add contacts to a list with mysql. My delete action isn't permanently remove the item. Not sure what I could to do after my setData. I added the timeout to see if it does in fact delete it, but it is not.

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get');
        setData(response.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []);

const deleteContact = (id) => {
        if(window.confirm ('Are you sure you want to DELETE your contact?')) {
            axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/api/remove/${id}`);
            toast.success('Contact deleted successfully');
            setData(
                data.filter((post) => {
                   return post.id !== id;
                })
            );
            setTimeout(() => {
                loadData();                
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

button that it uses

```
<button className='btn delete-btn' onClick={() => deleteContact(item.id)}>Delete</button>
```

MY api endpoint

```
app.delete('/api/remove/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body;
    const sqlRemove = `DELETE FROM contact_db WHERE id = ?`;
    db.query(sqlRemove,[ id ], (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: What is the loadData() will do here?

Comment: The loadData is my response for my api/get

Comment: ```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get');
        setData(response.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Since you are calling the loadData, you don't have to set the setData in deleteContact function. setData will run async so even if you call the loadData in the timeout the setData will execute after the timeout only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
const id = req.body;
```

Write

```
const id = req.params.id
```

Comment: I get a new error after changing a few thing.

sqlMessage: "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '[object Object]'"

Comment: Try this-



app.delete('/api/remove/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const sqlRemove = `DELETE FROM contact_db WHERE id = ${id}`;
    db.query(sqlRemove, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});